Bootstap Dropdown List of list - Why child list click close parent list?
I have two lists of data Parent list another each parent has a list of child data. After clicking parent child opened then incide any where on child the parent closed. I found found any answer. I am using spring boot thymleaf and bootstrap.
Here is my code
<ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <th:block th:each="key : ${accessDatas}">

                        <li class="list-group-item dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i>
                                <span class="menu-text"
                                    th:text="#{search.+${key.type}} + ' (' + ${key.count} + '/'+#{month} +')'"> </span>
                                <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="submenu" th:id="subMenu">
                                <th:block th:each="t : ${key.getAccessTypes()}">

                                    <li class="list-group-item dropdown ">
                                        <a th:href="${'#divData_'+ t.id}" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                            data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-list"></i>
                                            <span th:utext="${t.dataType}"></span> (<span
                                                th:utext="${t.count}"></span><span th:utext="#{'/'+#{month}}"></span>)
                                            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
                                        </a>



It could be because you're using the same data-toggle for both of them
